# performSegue not working since update to Xcode 9 (and iOS 11)

Tags: ios11, xcode9

On my app I have a Splash screen which checks if an user is already logged in with Facebook. If he is not, the splash screen pushes a login screen to the navigation stack. If the user is logged in, the splash screen also pushes the login screen but calls, on viewDidAppear of the login screen, a method that pushes the main app screen.

So, when the user is logged in I should see the following view controllers stack on my app:

`SplashViewController > LoginViewController > MainViewController.`

This flow worked without problems on iOS 9 and iOS 10.

However since I upgraded to iOS 11 this flow stopped working.

Now, if the user is logged in I the main view controller does not appear, only the login view controller remains visible. I checked on the debugger that performSegue to the main app screen is indeed called.

There are two weird details. The first is that the buttons on this login view controller don't work anymore (there is a button which calls the Facebook Login flow from the FacebookLogin SDK).

The second is that if I go to Xcode and click on the "Debug View Hierarchy" button, while Xcode is processing and creating the view hierarchy the main view controller suddenly appears on my app.

It seems that the main view controller is being pushed but its view is not being presented; so the segues on the LoginViewController don't work anymore. However, pressing "Debug View Hierarchy" seems to trigger something that updates the view hierarchy.

I am working with Xcode 9.0.1. This problem is happening both on the Xcode simulators and on my iPad Mini 2, which is currently running iOS 11.0.3.

Thanks.

Comment: I appear to have the same problem, but I am using KYDrawerController. If I remove the KYDrawerController then it works fine (apart from I lose my menu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly why this was happening, but I was able to solve this problem the following way.

On the SplashViewController, where I called the **direct** segue to the login view controller, which would call another segue on the viewWillAppear() method, I forced the segue to be performed on the main queue:

```
// SplashViewController
struct Identifier {
    static let login = "Login"
    static let direct = "Direct"
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    login()
}

func login() {
    // If there already exists a Facebook token we try to login directly.
    if let accessToken = AccessToken.current {
         bm.login(facebookToken: accessToken.authenticationToken, completion: { (error, user) in
            guard error == nil else {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Identifier.login, sender: self)
                return
            }
            // This call on the main queue wasn't needed on iOS 10
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Identifier.direct, sender: self)
            }
        })
    } else {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: Identifier.login, sender: self)
    }
}
```

then on LoginViewController:

```
// LoginViewController
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if direct {
        // Without calling the previous segue on the main queue this 
        // segue would be called but the pushed view controller's 
        // view would not appear on the screen until a refresh event 
        // was triggered.
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Identifier.direct, sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Felipe, you saved my life!, I didn't found any documentation about this issue, but I had this exact same problem on ios 11. This should be documented some where.